# Creating commerce users programmatically

Tags: 8, commerce

I need to import customer data from CSV files with billing and shipping data using Drupal 8.8 and Commerce 2.
I want to create the customer with its address data programmatically, but i do not know how to create billing and shipping.

I create the user as:

```
 $lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
 $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
 $user->setPassword('password');
 $user->enforceIsNew();
 $email="xyz@email.com";
 $user->setEmail($email);
 $user->setUsername($email);
 $user->set("init", $email);
 $user->set("langcode", $lang);
 $user->set("preferred_langcode", $lang);
 $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $lang);
 $user->activate();
 // Save user account.
 $user->save();
```

How do i create its billing and shipping data?

Comment: take a look at this https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2811529

Comment: Thanks @berramou , but it does not cover profiles creation with shipping address and billing address. I would have preferred not to go to Commerce source code to find billing and shipping field names.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Commerce, but from berramou's link it seems its profiles are drupal Entities, so you should be able to use Migrate API with the [Migrate Source CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv) plugin to populate them  with destination: `plugin: 'entity:profile'` in your migration yml.

Comment: Yes, Migrate is the route to go over custom scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got 2 options 1 migrate them, such as (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv) 
 or make an admin form to submit the csv file and get the content... 
but really you need to be create profiles for this billing info...

```
// Save user account.
$user->save();
// Add billing info. 
$the_user_created_id = $user->id();
$profileStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('profile');
$profile_data = [
 'type' => 'customer',
 'uid' => $the_user_created_id,
 'status'=> 1,
 'address' => [
   "langcode" => "",
   "country_code" => "AU",
   "administrative_area" => "NSW",
   "locality" => "SOME PLACE",
   "dependent_locality" => null,
   "postal_code" => "2000",
   "sorting_code" => null,
   "address_line1" => "Some Street",
   "address_line2" => "",
   "organization" => "47",
   "given_name" => "firstname",
   "additional_name" => null,
   "family_name" => "lastname",
  ],
];

$new_profile = $profileStorage->create($profile_data);
$new_profile->save();
```